# how to get <a> by title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to remove 3 classes from a specific `<a>` that is dynamically built. The only thing that is static is the title. How can I target/find an element by the title? I have googled around but nothing came up that looked like what I was wanting. If this is possible with CSS that would be great but I am expecting a javascript/jQuery answer either work for me.

The tag looks like:

```
<a href="javascript:%20openLookup%28%27%2F_ui%2Fcommon%2Fdata%2FLookupPage%3Flkfm%3Dj_id0%253Aj_id2%253AtheForm%26lknm%3Dj_id0%253Aj_id2%253AtheForm%253Aj_id77%26lktp%3D%27%20%2B%20getElementByIdCS%28%27j_id0%3Aj_id2%3AtheForm%3Aj_id77_lktp%27%29.value%2C670%2C%271%27%2C%27%26lksrch%3D%27%20%2B%20escapeUTF%28getElementByIdCS%28%27j_id0%3Aj_id2%3AtheForm%3Aj_id77%27%29.value.substring%280%2C%2080%29%29%29" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 noPadding" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:j_id77_lkwgt" onclick="setLastMousePosition(event)" title="Client Lookup (New Window)">
    <img src="/s.gif" alt="Client Lookup (New Window)" class="lookupIcon" onblur="this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onfocus="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" onmouseout="this.className = 'lookupIcon';this.className = 'lookupIcon';" onmouseover="this.className = 'lookupIconOn';this.className = 'lookupIconOn';" title="Client Lookup (New Window)">
</a>
```

Comment: show your markup atleast, i don't want to guess.

Comment: SO is for help with existing code so please post what you tried (jsfiddle are very welcome) or try and post it then if it fails.

Comment: When you say *a specific `a`* what do you mean, considering there are several `a` elements that have the same 'static' value in the `title` attribute? How do you single out that *specific one*?

Comment: I single it out by the Title. The specific element I am targeting is only displayed once per page I just do not have any control over the classes that are assigned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to select your hyperlink by title with CSS, use such syntax :

```
a[title='my title']
```

and the same with jQuery

```
$("a[title='my title']")
```

One working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hjanto1x/

Comment: 9 minutes and it will let me.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is very similar to css selectors. You can target the title like this:

```
$("a[title=x]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from jsFiddle. But I suppose it's should be something like this pseudo code.

```
$("selector").each("selector").find("attr name").each(function() {
$(this).removeClass();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"$(a[title="name"]).event();"
or
"$(a[title="name"]).method();"